# SSH remote command with !(pattern-list)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm trying to delete all files and directories under `/path/to/dir/` except for two directories (`dir1` and `dir2`) from a remote host using SSH. When I run a command similar to this on my local Ubuntu 14.04 box it works as expected:

```
user@host1:~$ cd /path/to/dir/ && rm -rf !(dir1|dir2)
```

If I try to execute the same command through SSH on another host with the same directory structure, it fails.

```
user@host1:~$ ssh user@host2 'cd /path/to/dir/ && rm -rf !(dir1|dir2)'
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `cd /path/to/dir/ && rm -rf !(dir1|dir2)'
```

How should I escape the command to make it work? I thought that using single quotes was enough.

Comment: What is the output of `ssh user@host2 'shopt -p extglob'`?

Comment: @John1024 Good catch. Indeed the other host returns `shopt -u extglob` which seems to mean `extglob = off`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really want to use bash patterns you can do this:

```
user@remote:~$ ls del/
1  2  3
user@desktop:~$ ssh remote.example 'PATTERN="!(1|2)" bash -O extglob -c "cd del && echo rm \$PATTERN"'
rm 3
```

I'd rather use find though (append `-delete` if you actually want to delete the files):

```
 user@desktop:~$ ssh remote.example 'cd del && find . ! -path . ! \( -name 1 -or -name 2 \)'
./3
```

Example with directories:

```
user@remote:~/del$ tree -F
.
├── 1/
│   └── 11/
├── 2/
│   └── 22/
└── 3/
    └── 33/
user@remote:~/del$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -path . ! \( -name 1 -or -name 2 \) -print0 | xargs -0 echo rm -r
rm -r ./3
```

Comment: Thanks to this I got it to work. By adding `dotblob`. My final version is `ssh user@host2 'bash -O extglob -O dotglob -c "cd /path/to/dir/ && rm -rf !(dir1|dir2)"'`. At first I was drawn to the pattern list approach because of its elegance and terseness but you are right - after adding all the needed options `find` looks simpler.